# The default value of an optional parameter must be constant. Dart

Tags: dart

I tried to make a default map parameter but it just goes errors for some reason,

```
var size = {
  "width": 1920,
  "height": 1080,
};

class MyClass {
  myFunction([String MyParam = "Sup!", Map background_size = size]) async {
    return background_size.width;
  }
}
```

It only gives me an errors like this `The default value of an optional parameter must be constant.` Can someone tell me which lines I type wrong?

Comment: The default value here is the `size` variable. You can make it a constant by declaring it with the `const` keyword. Like `const size = ...`

Comment: Ah makes sense, thank you for your answers it works well. @mmcdon20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution 1

Define `size` as `const`

```dart
const size = {
  "width": 1920,
  "height": 1080,
};

class MyClass {
  myFunction([String MyParam = "Sup!", Map background_size = size]) async {
    return background_size.width;
  }
}
```

### Solution 2

Set value if background_size is not set

```dart
var size = {
  "width": 1920,
  "height": 1080,
};

class MyClass {
  myFunction([String MyParam = "Sup!", Map? background_size]) async       {
    final _background_size = background_size ?? size;
    return _background_size.width;
  }
}
```